# Can $\mathbb{Z}_2$ be constructed as the closure of $4\mathbb{Z}+1$?

Tags: metric-spaces, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory

> Can $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ be constructed as the closure of $4\mathbb{Z}+1$?

I understand $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ is the closure of $2\mathbb{Z}+1$ in the 2-adic metric space.

I'm interested in whether the entirety of $2\mathbb{Z}+1$ is required.  In particular:

A) What's $X$, the closure of $4\mathbb{Z}+1$ in the 2-adic metric space?  And,

B) if $X\subsetneq\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ then can $X$ be extended to $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ by permitting the square root operation?

I'm motivated by the ideas of a) whether there's some way of "tidying up" the nontrivial kernel of the base 2 logarithm (a concept I only understand superficially), and b) since taking square roots in the 2-adics naturally extend numbers $\equiv1\mod 4$ to numbers $\equiv3\mod 4$; to what extent this process can generate the remainder of the 2-adic units from the half which are $\equiv1\mod4$.

Comment: What do you mean with $\mathbb Z_2$? I would read that as the field $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and the set of units would then be $\mathbb Z_2^\times=\{1\}$. But that is quite obviously not what you mean.

Comment: @celtschk: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the standard  notation for the $p$-adic integers; it's unfortunate that people use similar notation for quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$. I strongly advocate using $\mathbb{F}_q$ if you want to talk about the finite field of $q$ elements. Not only does this disambiguate notation, but it also gives you a way to denote finite fields that aren't of prime order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a $p$-adic ring, every set of the form

$$ a + m\mathbb{Z}_p = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_p \mid x \equiv a \bmod m \} $$

is both closed and open. (without loss of generality, we can restrict to $m$ being a power of $p$)

Thus, in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, you have $\overline{1 + 4 \mathbb{Z}} \subseteq 1 + 4 \mathbb{Z}_2$. It's not hard to show this is an equality.

Since  $ \mathbb{Z}_2^\times \cong \mu_2 \times (1 + 4 \mathbb{Z}_2) $, where $\mu_2 = \{ 1, -1 \}$, you can deduce that

$$ u \in \mathbb{Z}_2^\times \Longleftrightarrow u^2 \in 1 + 8 \mathbb{Z}_2 $$

(in fact, this equivalence can even pick out $\mathbb{Z}_2^\times$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}_2$)

Comment: Thanks. I guess overline indicates completion. But I don't follow your $u^2$ argument. If we denote $X'$ as $X$ extended by permitting square roots I'm thinking $t\in X\implies\sqrt{t}\in X'$ and one of $\sqrt{t}$ will be $\equiv3\mod 4$. I can't tally that up with what you wrote.

Comment: @RobertFrost: I guess don't understand where the disconnect is. That last formula almost literally contains "every square root of every element of $1 + 8 \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a unit, and every unit appears in this fashion". Are you overlooking the fact that, for example, $5$ doesn't have any square roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2$? (nor do 3 and 7)

Comment: You underestimate my ineptitude!  Okay; to confirm I understand correctly we have:  Completion of $4Z+1$ in the 2-adic metric is $1+4Z_2$.  This contains every square, so if we extend by permitting square roots we have $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$. So the upshot is what I wanted; namely that there is a natural way to say that $4Z_2+1$ are the positive integers and $4Z_2+3$ are the negative integers. Is all that fair?

Comment: By the overline I meant closure, but that amounts to the same thing here. I'd be hesitant to use the terms "positive" and "negative" here, but yes, that is the natural way to sort the $2$-adic integers into "things near $1$" and "things near $-1$". (also, note that $1 + 4 \mathbb{Z}_2$ contains nonsquares, such as $5$)

Comment: The equality $\overline{1 + 4 \mathbb{Z}} = 1 + 4 \mathbb{Z}_2$ - is $2$ the only prime for which this is true, or does it hold for other (all) primes?  I mean $1+p^n\Bbb Z_p=\overline{1+p^n\Bbb Z}$.

Comment: @user334732: Indeed $1+p^n \Bbb Z_p = \overline{1+p^n\Bbb Z}$ for all prime $p$ and natural $n$, although one maybe should be extra pedantic and say that in each case, the "overline" means completion, or closure in the respective $\Bbb Z_p$, *with respect to the $p$-adic metric / topology* -- i.e. for different $p$'s, these are different closure operations.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks, yes I meant using the appropriate metric - and always best to be extra pedantic if in doubt!